# Calling a non-static Variable from another Class

Tags: c#, variables, encapsulation

I want to call non-static variable from another class. If I make it static, it affects my other code.

I've two classes Harvest_Client and Harvest_Project.

In my Harvest_Project class I've

```
public int _client_id{ get; set;}
```

I'just want to do in Harvest_Client class is,

```
public int _id = Harvest_Project._client_id;
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Instantiate the class and access its getter methods !!!

Comment: Your naming is awfully non-standard. Propeties start with a Capital, not with a `_`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should rename the property (it's not a variable) to conform with .NET naming conventions, e.g.

```
public int ClientId { get; set; }
```

Next, you need an *instance* of `HarvestProject` (post-renaming). Don't just create a new one - you need the *right* instance, the one whose client ID you're interested in. We can't tell you which one it is - but if you don't already have an instance of `HarvestProject` to hand, you should work out how you're expecting to specify which client ID you want.

Think of it this way: if I were to ask you "How old is a person?" you'd naturally want to know *which* person I was talking about. It's exactly the same here.

Answer (score 1):

maybe passing the reference to the class will do what you need:

```
public class Harvest_Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int clientId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Harvest_Client
    {
        private Harvest_Project MyInstance;

        private int myid;

        public int MyId
        {
            get
            {
                return myid;
            }
            private set
            {
                MyId = value;
            }
        }
        public Harvest_Client(Harvest_Project cls)
        {
            MyInstance = cls;
            MyId = cls.clientId;//since class reference present no 
                                //need for the property.
                                //its just here to show if in your
                                //project you really just need ID
                                //in this example its redundant
        }

    }
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you can make a List of Harvest_Project objects or better a dictionary,if there are various types of "projects" they could be all placed in a dictionary cataloged accordingly to the specified key.

Answer (score 0):

One moment I would like to recommend to take into consideration the following declaration of property `public int ClientId {get; private set;"}` It allow you to prohibited setting this variable from third party code, if you actually need this. Otherwise you will have ordinary global variable